# Complex key bindings in Gtk

Tags: gtk3

Some text editors like sublime or atom support [complex key bindins](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html#key-chords), when you press and release two or more buttons while holding `Ctrl` or any other modifier key depressed to trigger some action.

There seems to be no direct support of such a concept in Gtk. Of course, one can do something like this:

```c
static second_event_happened = FALSE;

ctrl_k_cb () {
    g_timeout_add (500, ctrl_k_timeout, NULL) // queue watching function

    // adjust accels so that until timeout ctrl+t calls ctrl_k_t_cb
}

ctrl_k_timeout () {
    if (second_event_happened)
       second_event_happened = FALSE;
    else
       ctrl_k_function ();

    // reset accels to their normal state, i.e. ctrl+t calls ctrl_t_cb
}

ctrl_t_cb () {
    ...    
}

ctrl_k_t_cb () {
    second_event_happened = TRUE;

    ...
}
```

However, this approach is error-prone.
Is there a more simple or GTK-ish solution?

Comment: Are you trying, for example : `CTRL + D + K`  or  `CTRL + SHIFT + W` ? There is a difference, because the second one is easier.

Comment: @theGtknerd I know that multiple modkeys are supported by Gtk itself, but I'd love to use `ctrl + d + k`. `gtk_accelerator_parse("<ctrl>zx")` obviously fails.